# How to make all the dictionary values unique in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want a solution to make all the keys of a dictionary have a unique value, and to do that delete the values as minimum as possible to have each value unique. For example:

```
my_dict = {'c': 3, 'e': 3, 'a': 2, 'f': 2, 'd': 2}
```

for the above dictionary I need to sub 2 from 'f' and 3 of times from 'e' and 1 time from 'd'. and result would be 6 which means `{'c':3, 'a':2, 'd':1}`. Removing keys is not a problem.

note we could remove 'c' rather than 'e' or 'a' rather than f'' it's not important which key should be decreed or be removed , what matters is having unique values

This is what I have tried:

```
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    c = 0
    while len(my_dict.values()) > len(set(my_dict.values())):
        my_dict[k] = my_dict[k] -1
        c += 1
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Why is `e` removed altogether, leaving `c` unchanged? Why is `f` removed, while `d` is decremented and `a` is left alone?

Comment: We could remove c rather than e it's not important which key should be decreed or be removed , what matters is having unique values

Comment: That doesn't explain why `{'c': 3, 'a': 2}` wouldn't be the simplest result. Why does `d` stick around in decremented form at all?

Comment: Yes your point is correct and I will consider it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the result you were expecting, but it meets the requirements.

```
my_dict = {'c': 3, 'e': 3, 'a': 2, 'f': 2, 'd': 2}

to_remove = []
result = {}
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    while value > 0:
        if value not in to_remove:
            to_remove.append(value)
            result[key] = value
            break
        else:
            value -= 1
result
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach:

```
my_dict = {'c': 3, 'e': 3, 'a': 2, 'f': 2, 'd': 2}

rd = {v: k for k, v in my_dict.items()}
my_dict = {v: k for k, v in rd.items()}
print(my_dict)
```